# Index usage for NULL values

Tags: performance, index, mariadb

If there is index for a column, will it speed up search if condition is `... WHERE column IS NULL`? In fact it is composite index on 2 columns and second column can be NULL (`WHERE col1 = X AND col2 IS NULL`).

Comment: Are you asking whether MariaDB can use an index for a IS NULL predicate?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Yes. The question is mainly for MariaDB. Whether `column IS NULL` search condition will use index on `column` or the index is used only for non-NULL values (and IS NULL will do full scan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  It may.

Long answer:

`IS NULL` optimizes like `= constant`.  (`IS NOT NULL` does not.)

There are many reasons why the optimizer may shun the index and do a table scan, tossing rows that don't match.

For a single column index where the column is tested for `NULL` or a constant, the Optimizer will usually ignore the index if more than about 20% of the table has that value.

For a composite index (and all columns are tested for `NULL` or a constant, the Optimizer is likely to use the index.

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see whether the `INDEX` is likely to be used.